# How to design a working API for scores?

Tags: php, api, laravel

I have a table called scores and that table has two fields: team_id and score_value. What is the best way to write endpoint for this case:

First Option:
POST: scores/teams/{team_id}

```
public function($team_id,$score){
 $scores = new Scores();
 $scores->team_id = $team_id;
 $scores->score_value = $score;
 $scores->save();
}
```

Second Option:
POST: scores/teams
I could do the same this way too, so I don't really need to pass the team_id as an parameter since I can get that field inside insertion function like below for the logged in user:

```
public function($score){
 $scores = new Scores();
 $scores->team_id = Auth->user->team_id; (logged in user team id)
 $scores->score_value = $score;
 $scores->save();
}
```

So is the first option better than second option? in case I have a admin that adds also records on behalf of other users, so in this case we just pass the team_id as a parameter into the url.

Or would it be even better if I have both end-points, so I can use each of them depending whether is admin is adding or the normal user... for some reason I dont like this as it seems DRY.

I am kinda confused here which option to choose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly write API-s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605655/how-to-properly-write-api-s)

Comment: Are you using a framework like Laravel or Slim etc?

Comment: @brianlmerritt is it really important this? cz I dont see any importanc what kind of framework are u using, as api design should be the same for all frameworks, programming languages

Comment: @huuuk that's my question too, wich no one answered cz I thought that was not written well...

Comment: @HisniFazlija, you should edit your questions instead of create another one, if you need to improve it or add some extra data

Comment: @huuuk thanks for the advice, I will do that next times

Answer (score 0):

The second option is the best. Remember, if you are using POST method, do not insert arguments inside URL cause it's a BAD PRACTICE unless you are using GET/PUT/PATCH/DELETE.

And I also suggest [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) if you are writing API's.

Comment: What if Admin needs to add records on behalf of other users? this option will not work as the team id of user is taken from the logged in user, in this case admin does not have any team id, so it needs to be written another function like this where the team id should be passed as an argument, what do you say about this case?

Comment: It should be handled by forms or json, or any other option which you will get the team_id, just DO NOT put it inside the URL.

Comment: What do you mean by forms? with this I should have than two methods that actually do the same thing to insert a record into a table. doesnt this look DRY for you?

Comment: is it better that I can add a if stm to check if the user is admin, get the team_id from the request input, otherwise get it from the user->team_id logged in user? would this be the best with one function treat both cases?

Comment: The 'dry' way to create an API is to create middleware for functions such as authentication. Frameworks make this much easier, cleaner and dryer because the authentication code isn't sitting in the middle of the controller code.

Comment: You can remove the first option since you are using the second option. Both User and Admin can use that function, just add some checker if it's a user or admin then. You just need to have some way to pass the team_id in the api. Let's say for example a form with method POST, 
you have `<input type="text" id="team_id" />` and then call the API.
Then inside your API, get the data and insert it into a table. Then if it's a user, you just fetch the team_id because he's logged in. That way, you can get the team_id without having to write it inside the url.

Comment: @brianlmerritt I am not sure if I understood smth from your comment :s so are u saying which option is the best?

Comment: @Vashtamyty thanx for ur opinion, I guess I should do it that way... checking first to see what kind of User is and depending on that I can assign the team_id and the rest is pretty much the same.

Comment: @Vashtamyty I will keep open this question for a litle while to see if anyone else has any better solution for this. otherwise your answer will be marked as correct. thnx

Comment: Okay no problem ;)